# Can the MvcSiteMap work like the one in WebForms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

In webforms if a path is not accesable for a certain user, it will be hidden, can this be done with the MvcSiteMap?

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider

In Webforms all you need todo is

```
  <location path="SomePath">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="SomeRole" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

If you do not belong to the SomeRole the menu item will be hidden, possible in MvcSiteMap?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET the recommended way to define authorization is to use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx).

The `AuthorizeAttribute` is fully supported by MvcSiteMapProvider when `securityTrimming` is enabled. See [Registering the provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Registering-the-provider).

Comment: So if you want to change which roles have access to an area you have to recompile the site? I like the WebForms solution better then.. Oh well

Comment: @Anders - The WebForms solution was based on the fact that each web page exists in the physical world as a file. In MVC, there are no files. So, configuring security based on physical directory paths would be pointless. MVC is based on resources that are returned by controller action methods. The `AuthorizeAttribute` was designed to ensure that MVC resources are only available to authorized users by stopping the action from occurring. This is the only true measure of security in MVC (regardless of how "convenient" you perceive it to be). Note that ASP.NET 5 provides all config in code now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just in case someone else happens upon it, you can explicitly achieve what you are looking for by adding the roles attribute to your mvc.sitemap file where you register the nodes. Anyone not belonging to the role will not be able to see the node with that attribute.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="TheMenuOption" clickable="false"  roles="someRole">
```